# Aurelia Router hook - provide a pre instantiated and activated module

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm wondering if there is a hook in the router for providing an already instantiated module? And if I'm on the wrong track, what would be a better approach?

Consider this situation...

- I have a model in my domain called Contract.
- Users can search for Contracts.
- Users can open multiple different Contract instances in separate tabs

Following is a section of a UI that shows how this might look with multiple contracts opened in tabs...
[image: tab-example-screen-cut]

Here you can see a contract nav level that has a Search tab (static and always open) plus 3 contracts that have been opened by the user *123456*, *789102*, and *987654*.

Is there a way I can use the router to do something like this? So once a contract has been opened, if the user switches away and switches back, I can just provide the already loaded and activated module from the initial visit?

At the moment I have solved it using a kind of contract container VM which is a wrapper, coupled with a kind of cache of open contract models. The tabs themselves are built from the contracts in the cache, and when the container is activated (by routing to /contract/:id) it searches the cache for a contract by that id and if found uses that otherwise loads the contract and then displays it via compose...

I proto'd this [here](https://github.com/simonfox/aurelia-tabs/tree/master/src). The container VM looks like:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Contracts} from './contracts';

@inject(Contracts)
export class ContractContainer {
  constructor(openContracts) {
    this.id = '';
    this.openContracts = openContracts;
    this.contract = null;
  }

  activate(params) {
    this.id = 'Contract ' + params.id.toString();
    this.contract = this.openContracts.getOrCreateContractByKey(params.id);
  }
}
```

And the view:

```
<template>
  <compose view-model.bind="contract"/>
</template>
```

Comment: Interesting use-case- question for you, in the example screenshot above, what is currently in the browser's address-bar?
http://foo.com/#contracts/123456/spot-laydown or
http://foo.com/#contracts/123456 or 
http://foo.com/#contracts

Comment: @JeremyDanyow I'd be wanting the url to be foo.com/#contracts/123456/spot-laydown if possible

Comment: @JeremyDanyow any suggestions?

Comment: For anyone with a Caliburn.Micro background I could do something like this with the `Conductor<T>.Collection.OneActive`

Comment: Right now there's no easy way to get the router to cache an inactive view/view model, but that work is planned for a future release.

Answer (score 1):

Simon,

I downloaded and ran your test project to try to understand what you are doing here, and here are my thoughts:

The Contacts page would have a child router, and the child router creates the tabs.  When a user selects a tab, the router navigates to the item id.

In the activate event, grab the id and pull the data that goes with that contract and display it.  The data could be in memory, local storage, or from a database.

So you don't try to have the router load an already created view, you just grab the current contract entity and bind it up.

To the user, it will look like it is going to a different tab, but it reality, it is the same UI, just different data.

Bind to the contract entity, not to a property of the viewModel.  Then when you swap entities, all of the prior data will already be in the entity.  For example bind

Comment: this sounds very similar to the approach I have prototyped?

Comment: Similar, but you are trying to load an existing/new views.  In other words, you have many views.  In the suggested approach, there is only one view and viewmodel. You just change the contract..

Comment: isn't that basically what my `ContractContainer` module does?

Comment: I re-read your post a bit more thoroughly, and it does indeed look it does. :)   That is the way I would do it as well.